# Data Annotation in net core not working with list

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations

I have a list with a class and inside the class I have data annotations.
When in view I show the list in the browser debugger, I only get the first element of the list with the data annotation that I have defined previously.
The rest of the elements only have the maxlength tag but the data-vals do not appear
my code is the following:

class:

```
public partial class Employee
{   
    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class employee_view_model
{
    public List<employee> listEmployee { get; set; }    
}
```

View:

```
foreach (var item in Model.listEmployee.OrderBy(z => z.Title))
{
   @await Html.PartialAsync("_Row_Employ", new Employee()
   {
      Title = item,                            
   })                        
}
```

Result:
The first element is correct.

```
<input class="form-control input-sm text-uppercase valid" data-val="true" data-val-length="max 25" data-val-length-max="25" data-val-required="The Title field is required." id="employ_Title" maxlength="25" name="employ.Title" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Example 1" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="employ_Title-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

The rest of the elements are shown as the following example:
The data-val does not appear.

```
<input class="form-control input-sm text-uppercase " id="employ_Title" maxlength="25" name="employ.Title" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Example 2">
```

Why only put the data annotation in the first element of the list?

Comment: Try to generate some random id for every element for (id attribute). for example employ_Title1, employ_Title2,employ_Title3, etc

Comment: @Majid if I make an array and generate the Html.TextBoxFor (x => x.listEmployee [i] .Title) as follows, it generates employ_Title1, employ_Title2, employ_Title3, etc and then the data-val appear in all the fields. This in .net MVC 5 worked correctly the way I have it done in the example.
I don't know why in .net Core this has changed and now we have to make arrays.
Thanks for the help.